# htaccess rewrite to a default directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm stuck in a situation with htaccess - None of the previous solutions in stack seems to help me so I'm writing a new one. Here is the problem:

I want all the requests to be looked into `http://www.example.com/folder/public_html/` by default and if the requested resource doesnt exist in that folder, the request should be routed to `http://www.example.com/index.php`

Example:
I place a request for `http://www.example.com/example.php`, so by default, the server should look into `/folder/public_html/example.php` and if the file is not there then it should be routed via the index file in the root of the site i.e. `/index.php?request=example.php`

Please help, I'm badly stuck

Answer (score 1):

Create a .htaccess with this rule in the directory `http://www.example.com/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/public_html/$1 [L]
```

And a .htaccess with this in `http://www.example.com/folder/public_html/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [R]
```

(If you only want to show /index.php?request=example.php but do not want the browser to redirect, use [L] instead of [R])

**Edit:**

If you want to *redirect* to /folder/public_html/file.php if the *file exists*, add these lines in the second .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R]
```

*By default* the file /folder/public_html/file.php is shown if it exists because of the rewrite rule in the first .htaccess, but the browser *doesn't redirect*.